# ASP.NET API binding value from POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, post

I would like to ask somebody, how to correct prepare collection of classes to binding values from [FromBody].

I have three classes:

```
public class Point
{
 public int? X {get; set;}
}

public class CollectionPoint
{
 public List<Point> Point {get; set;}
}

public class TestBlock
{
 public string? Name {get; set;}
 public List<CollectionPoint> CollectionPoint {get; set;}
}
```

Than  I have methods for reading JSON object, like:

```
public string Post([FromBody] TestBlock testBlock)
```

Finally, I have testing JSON,like:

```
{
    "Name":"Block1",
    "CollectionPoint":
    [
      {
        "Point":{"X":"20"},
        "Point":{"X":"22"},
        "Point":{"X":"25"} 
      },
      {
        "Point":{"X":"40"}
      }
    ]
}
```

But problem is, that this solution doesnt work. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear.
Do you want a collection of Points ?
If so there is an extra class somwhere.

```
public class Point
{
 public int? X {get; set;}
}

public class TestBlock
{
 public string? Name {get; set;}
 public List<Point> CollectionPoint {get; set;}
}
```

Do you want a collection of a collection of points?
If so the json is malformed, it should be:

```
{
    "Name":"Block1",
    "CollectionPoint":
    [
        {
            "Point":
            [
                {"X":"20"},
                {"X":"22"},
                {"X":"25"} 
            ]
        },
        {
            "Point":
            [
                {"X":"20"}
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need collection of CollectionPoint and this object can containt collection of Points. I try your JSON example, but without result.